# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtk'

Tags: python, pycharm, gtk, pygtk

I've tried to follow several solutions on the internet also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63832559/gtk-problem-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-gtk) one, but no luck. I'm in the process of implementing a object detection system. I am on Windows 10, and using PyCharm using python-3.8

I am getting errors for the packages, I've tried to add them through the package installer and through the terminal, no luck. Here's the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/CabaleGame/runner.py", line 2, in <module>
    import processCards
  File "D:\CabaleGame\processCards.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gtk.gdk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtk'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've downloaded the package from [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyGTK/#files) and [here](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows), which one is correct?

My program file:

```
    import gtk.gdk
    import cv
    import time
    import os
    import string
    
    def takeScreenCapture(screenShotNum = ""):
        time.sleep(1)
        
        w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
        sz = w.get_size()
        #print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
        pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
        pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
    
        # Convert gtk.PixelBuf to a NumPy array
        array = pb.get_pixels_array()
    
        # Convert NumPy array to CvMat
        mat = cv.fromarray(array)
    
        # Convert RGB to BGR
        cv.CvtColor(mat, mat, cv.CV_RGB2BGR)
    
        #cv.ShowImage("win",mat)
        #cv.WaitKey(0)
    
        return mat
    
    def getMeaningFromCards(cards):
        """
        This takes a dictionary of the form:
             (x, y) : Card image
        and returns a dictionary of the form:
             (x, y) : (number, suit)
    
        (x, y) are the coordinates of the top left of the card
        """
    
        imgdir = "LibraryImages"
        templatesNums = os.listdir(os.path.join(imgdir,"Numbers"))
        templatesSuits = os.listdir(os.path.join(imgdir,"Suits"))
                                   
        #templates = filter(lambda s: s[-4:] == ".png", templates)
        templatesNums = map(lambda s: os.path.join(imgdir,"Numbers", s), templatesNums)
        templatesSuits = map(lambda s: os.path.join(imgdir, "Suits",  s), templatesSuits)    
    
    
        for k in cards.keys():
            card = cards[k]
    
            cardImg = cv.CreateImageHeader((card.width, card.height), 8, 3)
            cv.SetData(cardImg, card.tostring())
    
            numAndSuit3 = cv.GetSubRect(cardImg, (0,0,30,80))
    
            numAndSuit1 = cv.CreateImage((numAndSuit3.width, numAndSuit3.height), 8, 1)
            cv.CvtColor(numAndSuit3, numAndSuit1, cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)
            # Convert the 1 channel grayscale to 3 channel grayscale
            # (GRAY2RGB doesn't actually introduce color)
            cv.CvtColor(numAndSuit1, numAndSuit3, cv.CV_GRAY2RGB)
            
    
            num = findBestTemplateMatch(templatesNums, numAndSuit3)
            suit = findBestTemplateMatch(templatesSuits, numAndSuit3)
            #print num, suit
    
            # If this image was recognized as a card, but didn't match
            # any template, it shouldn't be in the list in the first place
            if num == None or suit == None:
                del cards[k]
                continue
    
    
            num = string.split(os.path.basename(num), '.')[0]
            suit = string.split(os.path.basename(suit), '.')[0]
    
            # The alternate file names have underscores
            # after their names
            if num[-1] == '_':
                num = num[:-1]
    
            if suit[-1] == '_':
                suit = suit[:-1]
    
            cards[k] = (num, suit)
    
            #cv.ShowImage("NumandSuit", numAndSuit)
            #cv.WaitKey(0)
    
        print
        cards
        return cards
    
    
    def findBestTemplateMatch(tplList, img):
        """
        Compares img against a list of templates.
        tplList is a list of string filenames of template images
        Returns a tuple (num, suit) if a template is suitably matched
        or None if not
        """
        
        minTpl = 200 # arbitrarily large number
        tString = None
        
        for t in tplList:
            tpl = cv.LoadImage(t)
            
            w = img.width - tpl.width + 1
            h = img.height - tpl.height + 1
            result = cv.CreateImage((w,h), 32, 1)
            cv.MatchTemplate(img, tpl, result, cv.CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
            
            (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv.MinMaxLoc(result)
    
            #print t
            #print (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc)
    
            # 0.2 found by experiment (the non-card images end up being around
            # 0.25 - 0.28, and all the card images were much around 0.08 and less
            if minVal < minTpl and minVal < 0.2:
                minTpl = minVal
                tString = t
    
    
        #print minTpl, tString
        #cv.ShowImage("win", img)
        #cv.ShowImage("win2", result)
        #cv.WaitKey(0)
    
        return tString
            
    
    def extractCards(fileName = None):
        """
        Given an image, this will extract the cards from it.
    
        This takes a filename as an optional argument
        This filename should be the name of an image file.
    
        This returns a dictionary of the form:
            (x, y) : Card image
        It is likely that the output from this will go to the
        getMeaningFromCards() function.
        """
        
        if fileName == None:
            mat = takeScreenCapture()
        else:
            mat = cv.LoadImage(fileName)
    
        # First crop the image: but only crop out the bottom.
        # It is useful to have all dimensions accurate to the screen
        # because otherwise they will throw off the mouse moving and clicking.
        # Cropping out the bottom does not change anything in terms of the mouse.
        unnec_top_distance = 130
        unnec_bottom_distance = 40
        margin = 50
        submat = cv.GetSubRect(mat, (0,0,mat.width, mat.height - unnec_bottom_distance))
        subImg = cv.CreateImageHeader((submat.width, submat.height), 8, 3)
        cv.SetData(subImg, submat.tostring())
    
    
        gray = cv.CreateImage((submat.width, submat.height), 8, 1)
        cv.CvtColor(submat, gray, cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)
    
        thresh = 250
        max_value = 255
        cv.Threshold(gray, gray, thresh, max_value, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)
    
        cv.Not(gray,gray)
        #cv.ShowImage("sub", submat)
        #cv.WaitKey(0)
    
        storage = cv.CreateMemStorage (0)
    
        cpy = cv.CloneImage(gray)
        contours = cv.FindContours( cpy, storage, cv.CV_RETR_LIST, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, (0,0) );
        #contours = cv.ApproxPoly(contours, cv.CreateMemStorage(), cv.CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, 3, 1)
    
        bboxes = []
    
        if contours:
            while(contours):
                area = cv.ContourArea(contours)
                # It turns out that all the cards are about 44000 in area...
                # It would definitely be nice to have a better way to do this:
                # ie, find the size of the card programmatically and use it then
                if(area > 44000 and area < submat.width*submat.height*2/3):
                    bb = cv.BoundingRect(contours)
                    bboxes.append(bb)
                contours = contours.h_next()
    
        #drawBoundingBoxes(bboxes, submat)
    
        # cards is a dictionary of the form:
        #    (x, y) : card
        cards = {}
        
        for box in bboxes:
            card = cv.GetSubRect(subImg, box)
            #cv.ShowImage("card", card)
            #cv.WaitKey(0)
            cards[(box[0], box[1])] = card
    
        return cards
        
    
    def drawBoundingBoxes(bb, img):
        for b in bb:
            x = b[0]
            y = b[1]
            width = b[2]
            height = b[3]
            cv.Rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+width, y+height), (0,255,0,0))
    
        cv.ShowI

mage("bb", img)
    cv.WaitKey(0)


def drawSquares(listWithPoints,img):
    for l in listWithPoints:
        for p in range(len(l)-1):
            cv.Line(img, l[p], l[p+1], (0,0,255,0),2)
        cv.Line(img, l[-1], l[0], (0,0,255,0),2)

    #cv.ShowImage("sub", img)
    #cv.WaitKey(0)    

def contourToPointList(contour):
    plist = []
    for (x,y) in contour:
        plist.append((x,y))
        
    return plist


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cards = extractCards('CardImages/4_heart.jpg')
    print
    cards
    #c = cards[cards.keys()[0]]
    #print c
```

Is it possible to add it manually through the folders?
Would it work if i put the package her:

```
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include
```

Answer (score 1):

From python documentation :

Replace `import gtk.gdk` by :

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "insert your gtk version")
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

Comment: To clarify version here is either 3.0 or 4.0. pygtk (2.0) has been dead for a very long time.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification